# How do i programmatically logout user?[Django]

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, oauth, django-rest-framework

I know to logout user in Django. If i want to logout user, i would do

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
```

But what is the relevant way of logging out the user if i am using django oauth toolkit(DOT)?

Should i follow the same or delete the token? Some says delete the token and some says expiry period should be expired. Please provide me the best possible resolution for logging out in DRF using DOT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [Revoking an OAuth2 Token](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_04.html)

> You’ve granted a user an Access Token, following part 1 and now you would like to revoke that token, probably in response to a client request (to logout).

And [Do you logout a user who login via OAuth2 by expiring their Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666124/do-you-logout-a-user-who-login-via-oauth2-by-expiring-their-access-token)

#### EDIT

```
# OAuth2 provider endpoints
oauth2_endpoint_views = [
    url(r'^authorize/$', oauth2_views.AuthorizationView.as_view(), name="authorize"),
    url(r'^token/$', oauth2_views.TokenView.as_view(), name="token"),
    url(r'^revoke-token/$', oauth2_views.RevokeTokenView.as_view(), name="revoke-token"),
]
```

If you follow the tutorial part2 you will find you already have the revoke-token url, so you just need to send request to this url.

#### EDIT2

Let me try to explain this clearly

When you use Django OAuth Toolkit and DRF, you usually will use

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    )
}
```

And you can get access token by

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" -u"<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

And get response like this

```
{
    "access_token": "<your_access_token>",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 36000,
    "refresh_token": "<your_refresh_token>",
    "scope": "read write groups"
}
```

Now you can use your access_token to request the api you set like this

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <your_access_token>" http://localhost:8000/users/1/
```

**How to logout depends on how you define login**

Website define login from the session in cookies. When you developing a mobile app, You will define login depend on message in your app ([user credentials present in keychain or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295504/ios-how-to-authenticate-a-user-after-login-for-auto-login) when it comes to IOS), and that is what your code do:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
```

You can see source code here [django-logout](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7549eb000430192833f05186056d1ae20b0d17ad/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L133) and docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush)

> flush()
>
> Deletes the current session data from the session and deletes the session cookie. This is used if you want to ensure that the previous session data can’t be accessed again from the user’s browser (for example, the django.contrib.auth.logout() function calls it).

But remember, From [Luke Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557044/delete-access-token-after-logout)

> The lifetime of the access_token is independent of the login session of a user who grants access to a client. OAuth2 has no concept of a user login or logout, or a session, so the fact that you expect a logout to revoke a token, would seem to indicate that you're misunderstanding how OAuth2 works. You should probably clarify in your question why you want things to work this way and why you need OAuth.

Finally In your case, I think you need to revoeke the token before logout:

```
def revoke-token(request):
    # just make a request here
    # POST /o/revoke_token/ HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded token=XXXX&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=XXXX
    

def logout(request):
    response = revoke-toke(request)
    # if succeed
    logout(request)
```

Comment: So i should send token, client_id and client_secret(if confidential) from front end(through headers in ajax ) and call above function of logout(request) like in question?

Comment: Yes, you can follow the tutorial.

Comment: It is all about curl no views part. I am having hard to program it in views. I am blank on how exactly my views should be? I will first follow the tutorial of curl part then.

Comment: You just need to post the parameters to your api, it doesn't matter if you use DRF or not if only for logout.

Comment: I am using DRF for backend. I want to develop a moble app. Posting the parameters to your api means passing parameters from headers to my view. The url should be like /customer/logout/?token= & client_id= & client_secret= which maps to my view

Comment: Where should be my logout view then? Can you please just create a skeleton and which url to pass from frontend ? No logic just skeleton(Like if i want to logout using normal authentication i would have a url and views as) url(r'^/user/logout/', UserLogout.as_view(), name="user_logout") and class UserLogout .... . In frontend i would pass action = {% url 'user_logout' %}. If from ajax i would do url:'/user/logout/'. Can you please just create a structure like i have create ? I will mark it as answered and it will be easier to grasp the process flow programatically.

Comment: Now there is no room for confusion. I highly appreciate you. A boundless thank to you for being my teacher.:)